# how to access a local variable in another function

Tags: python

```
    chose=random.choice(words)
    print(chose)
    i=0
    while i<chance:#ici nous crayons une boucle qui va nous permettre de repeter une instruction 8 fois
        guess=input("\n Devinez une lettre qui peut se trouver dans ce truc.")
        print("\n")
        final_word=""
        point=0
        if (guess==chose and i<chance):#si cette instruction st remplie on a gagner
            point=chance-(i)
            print("Vous vennez de gagner\n")
            print(point)
            break
        elif(guess!=chose):
            for character in chose:
                if character in guess:
                    final_word +=character   
                else:
                    final_word +="*"
        print(final_word)
        i+=1



#cette fonction nous aide à mettre sur place le nom et le score du jouer   
def login():
    user=input("Quel est votre nom ? ")
    user=user.capitalize()
    print("Bonjour monsieur {} et bienvenu dans le jeu.".format(user))

    score={
        user:point
    }
    with open('donee','wb') as db:
        my_pickler=pickle.Pickler(db)
        my_pickler.dump(score)
```

up there you can see my code, I want the result of my variable 'point' in the function traitement to be desplayed in the dictionary score;
how can i do that?

Comment: Have you learned about passing and returning values?

Comment: Also, I think your code is a bit incomplete.

Comment: Welcome to SO! One of the main points of functions is that you can't access variables in other functions. Functions take input as arguments/parameters and return values and operate locally, or as locally as possible (i.e. not mutate their input, be idempotent, not access or modify global state, etc).

Comment: A nice trick for StackOverflow is to write a small toy program that demonstrates the problem with no extra fluff. Your example is missing the top of the function you are concerned about but also has some queries fors and ifs that don't have anything to do with the problem. It just makes it harder for us to answer your question.

Comment: `def login(point): ...` and run it as `login(50)` to send value ie. 50 to `score`

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Local variables are by definition exactly that. You *could* use global values, but that is asking for trouble.

You can easily solve the problem by passing parameters to functions, and returning values from those functions.